# Fingerprint Data Storage

Tags: android, fingerprint, biometrics, tee

Reading up on how TEE functions, it is currently not possible to do so just like it is stated in the question. How can we can utilize the TEE Client API or create apps Trusted Applications that enable us to store more than 5 finger print images inside any vendor's TEE.

Comment: The 5 FP limit is not arbitrary. It's a value set by the FP hardware vendor based on the device's ability to match against that many FPs in a reasonable time. To change that you'll need to work with the FP hardware vendor and it probably requires modification of the Android system. It's not something that you'll typically be able to change externally.